# Is it possible to use localStorage like private env variable?

Tags: node.js, local-storage, angular5, environments

I mean Is it possible to set some variables privately. Values of keys can't see in site's files. I use Angular 5 + nodejs Expressjs. process.env.blablabal helps me for backend but not client

Comment: What do you mean by "private" ? Do you mean as "can only be seen by one user", or "cannot be seen by any user" ? LocalStorage can be seen and modified by the client, so please keep in mind that `the client cannot be trusted`

Comment: **No/Null/Any** sensitive information may be stored clientside, nor be contained in any file that ever gets served to a client. Any key/password/etc. that has been served to a client must be seen as unsafe